# iOS Framework creation storing developer keys

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I am currently creating my first iOS Framework and thus questioning myself regarding every step.

At the moment I need the developers using my SDK's to provide a key and a secret in order to be able to access my features, but I'm not sure how to structure the SDK classes for storing session data. Mainly I need to create a kit which will consist of separate frameworks, but with the condition for all the frameworks to be able to access the key and the secret.

So, even if the developer only uses Framework A he should be able to provide the credentials in the same way as if he would also be using Framework B and Framework C from my SDK.

My option is kind of SessionData singleton inside the SDK which will have them as static variables. So basically the code will be something like:

```
[MySDK setClientSecret:@"clientSecret"];
```

But, how do I proceed with SessionData class if the developer includes only Framework A or only Framework B, instead of the whole SDK set?

Do I repeat this class in all the frameworks? What is the approach for this?

Comment: Isn't that the client's problem?  They pass the secret to you each time the app starts and you store it in an instance variable of the singleton.

Comment: This is what I'm asking. I'm not sure how this cross SDK's singleton class should be treated.

Comment: you miss the point, @trojanfoe is saying that these keys aren't stored inside your SDK - the user adds your SDK to their app and then when they run it they pass in all of the required keys. if you do get the point then is isn't clear what you mean by `cross SDK's singleton`

Comment: no, I don't miss the point. I don't want to store them locally, it's logical that they'll be providing it whenever they use whatever SDK. I will reedit the question.

Comment: please let me know if I should reedit the question or provide other context.

Comment: If the client is passing the secret at runtime then they will expect to use the code you provide in your question.  You can then just store this in an instance variable.  If your issue is that multiple frameworks will use the same secret then you need to provide that singleton class in a separate framework and your other frameworks can collect it from that framework whenever they want it.  This will mean your users will need to link against at least 2 of your frameworks.

Comment: @trojanfoe, yep, I guess this is the only way - separate framework for storing. Unfortunately that adds too much complexity for nothing.. I'll just provide the kit, without separating the frameworks. I looked at GoogleMapsSDK and they also have a big bunch of functionality which they didn't care of separating into different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an SDK that just needs a secret or client access key, then you could always store them as User defined values in your build settings, and then access them through

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionary:@"SECRET_KEY"]`

Or if you are stored session tokens, then you could store that as a property with a user model and persist it with Core data or the cache or something.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights. Unfortunately I'm making the SDK for which the developer will have to provide the secret and I'm just wondering of how can I make it in a proper way.